# Android 4.1.1 not playing mp4 Video

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-video-player, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing an android application which plays videos stored on SD Card. Android 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.1.2 is playing the videos with out any issue but Android 4.1.1 is showing "Can not play this video" dialog.
Whats the issue?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: encoding is needed -H.263

Comment: thanks, can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: use any online **android video** convert that will work for u

Comment: will try this..thanks..any one you can recommend?

Comment: just google once or provide me video once..

Comment: i need video to be of mp4 format only i converted it to H.264 but it didnt help..and H.263 codec is not there in video converter apps

Comment: is it possible for u to provide me video?

Comment: i would have provided it..but this is client resource so i cant :(..can you guide me?

Comment: yes i will provide you that..can you provide me your email id?

Comment: i am unable to find that :P..sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42781/discussion-between-rauf-and-monica)